# AndroidViewClient: junk after document element

Tags: android, automation, androidviewclient

I tried to take dump on Samsung S6.

```
$dump
```

Following is the output I received (last line):

```
</hierarchy>sh: resetreason: can\'t execute: Permission denied\r\nKilled \r\n
```

Which permission is denied and who's getting killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the output sent by the device contains those lines.
**AndroidViewClient** uses, by default and also depending on android version, `uiautomator dump` to obtain the information it needs.

You can try

```
$ adb shell
$ uiautomator dump
```

to verify if the lines are there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. uiautomator gave me same output. Not an issue of AndroidViewClient.